# Find file by name in a specific directory but not in its subdirectoriers

Tags: unix, find

In order to find a file by name, I have this command:

```
find . /home/XYZ/ -name '*abc*'
```

But it shows results in the directory XYZ and its subdirectories. I only need to search inside the specific folder "XYZ", not in the subdirectories.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
find . XYZ/ -maxdepth 1 -name *abc*
```

**OUTPUT**

```
find . XYZ/ -maxdepth 1 -name *abc* 
XYZ/abc.txt

find . XYZ/  -name *abc* 
./XYZ/abc.txt
./XYZ/tuv/123abc
XYZ/abc.txt
XYZ/tuv/123abc
```

```
man find

      -maxdepth levels
              Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the starting-points.  Using
              -maxdepth 0 means only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.
```